# Component Object Model via C++

Tags: object, model, automation, com, components

I want to use object of my software using COM interface my code is :

```
::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
IID iid;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);
IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
DISPID dispid;
DISPPARAMS params = {NULL};
OLECHAR * Name = OLESTR("addSimulationCase");
HRESULT hresult =pWMPDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, 
&Name,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
hresult =pWMPDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL,
                      NULL);  
//pdisp IDispatch
_ASSERT(hr==S_OK);
```

I don't know what is exactly param that is one of input argument of invoke.
please Help me I am a dummy in C++.